# How to append nested state for a particular data?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of an object where course detail is available in a state. which I have rendered in other component using the map when you click on a particular course it shows title, description and a textarea box where user can give a comment.  I want the particular comment to be shown to a particular course only, a comment should be an array.

[Project Link (codeSandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-haze-tf9cy)

---

**state**

```
state={
data: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Reactjs",
        Description:
          "React is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces. It is maintained by Facebook and a community of individual developers and companies. React can be used as a base in the development of single-page or mobile applications, as it is optimal for fetching rapidly changing data that needs to be recorded.",
        comment: []
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Bootstrap",
        Description:
          "Bootstrap is a free and open-source CSS framework directed at responsive, mobile-first front-end web development. It contains CSS- and JavaScript-based design templates for typography, forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components",
        comment: []
      }
    ],
}
```

**get Detail of the particular course (function)**

```
handleData = data => {
    this.setState({
      DetailData: data
    });
  };
```

**getting input value**

```
handleInput = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };
```

**updating comment (facing issue while updating)**

```
handleSubmit = commentid => {
    const com = this.state.name;
    const updateComment = this.state.datas.map(c => {
      if (c.id === commentid) {
        return {
          ...c,
          comment: [...this.state.comment, com]
        };
      } else {
        return c;
      }
    });
    this.setState({
      datas: updateComment,
      name: ""
    });
  };
```

Comment: Where did you call `handleSubmit()`?

Comment: I have created a comment box component where the textarea box is available,  there I have called handlesubmit  function . CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-haze-tf9cy

Comment: I already checked your code, there's nowhere in the `CommentBox` component you called `handleSubmit()`. Also, there's no `textarea` state or a `ref` to the comment text which you can pass to the `handleSubmit()` function.

Comment: path for comment box                  
              src>Components>CommentBox>CommentBox.js  @AkshitMehra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few missing pieces for your code. First of all, as you guessed you are not updating the comment part right. It should be:

```
handleSubmit = (commentid, event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const com = this.state.name;
  const updateComment = this.state.datas.map(c => {
    if (c.id === commentid) {
      return {
        ...c,
        comment: [...c.comment, com]
      };
    } else {
      return c;
    }
  });
  this.setState({
    datas: updateComment,
    name: ""
  });
};
```

Notice that part: `comment: [...c.comment, com]`
It is not `this.state.comment` it is the part of the mapped item: `c`

Also, `handleInput` should be like this:

```
handleInput = e => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    });
  };
```

I couldn't see any named property in your state. It is just `name`.

And my last part but maybe not your last part since there might be other problems, your `CommentBox` component should be like that:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Contx } from "../../../ContextApi";

const CommentBox = ({ bid }) => {
  const { handleInput, handleSubmit } = useContext(Contx);
  return (
    <div>
      <hr />
      <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(bid, e)}>
        <textarea
          onChange={handleInput}
          name="comment"
          placeholder="Enter Comment"
        />
        <button className="btn btn-success" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have only change handle submit.  in handleInput i  am using event.target.name,  so whatever name will be there it will grab the value.